# ASW-SDK S3 Upload Abort

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want abort an upload, but calling `upload.abort()` raise an error `Upload aborted.`. How abort the upload silently (without error)?

```
import { PutObjectCommandInput, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { Progress, Upload } from "@aws-sdk/lib-storage";

const uploadParams: PutObjectCommandInput = {
  Bucket: 'my-bucket',
  Key: 'my-file',
  Body: file,
};

const upload: Upload = new Upload({
  client: s3Client,
  params: uploadParams,
});

// abort after 3 seconds
setTimeout(() => upload.abort(), 3000);

// start upload
upload.done();
```

I have also tried to catch the promise

```
upload.abort().then().catch(() => {
  // ...
})
```

And also tried to try catch all

```
try {
  upload.abort().then().catch(() => {
    // ...
  })
} catch () {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is actually being thrown from the `upload.done` Promise.

You can check the code [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/62657b13af635928bf2c5ee8f449be711a379dd9/lib/lib-storage/src/Upload.ts#L295-L297) and [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/62657b13af635928bf2c5ee8f449be711a379dd9/lib/lib-storage/src/Upload.ts#L340-L342)

For your case, you would want something like the following:

```
const upload: Upload = new Upload({
  client: s3Client,
  params: uploadParams,
});

// abort after 3 seconds
setTimeout(() => upload.abort(), 3000);

try {
  // start upload
  upload.done();
} catch (err) {
    if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
      // Handle gracefully
    }
}
```